# Erro na exportação de arquivo MySQL "ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file"

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query, exportação

Olá, estava tendo alguns problemas para exportar uma tabela em formato csv do meu database no Mysql em decorrência das definições do "secure_file_priv"... realizei as seguintes alterações:

Criei um diretório no raiz e dei permissões:
sudo mkdir /mysqlfiles
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql  /mysqlfiles/

Quando dou o comando no banco ''SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";'' o retorno é:

+------------------+--------------+

| Variable_name    | Value        |

+------------------+--------------+

| secure_file_priv | /mysqlfiles/ |

+------------------+--------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Até aí, ok. Quando tento exportar algo com o comando " SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela into outfile '/mysqlfiles/nome_do_arquivo';"  o retorno é:

ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/conseguiu.txt' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Eu estava realizando vários testes, em certo momento consegui exportar o arquivo sem maiores problemas, agora, parece que ele não tem permissão para escrever no diretório para o qual eu dei a permissão de exportação.

PS: Já tentei criar diretórios fora do raiz, e mudar as permissões para "chmod 777 ", logar como root mas nada deu certo. Inclusive, se as permissões do diretório estiverem como "chmod 777" o mysql nem sobe o serviço pois estou apontando a exportação para um diretório que, aparentemente, não se enquadra nas políticas de segurança do serviço.

Comment: tente exportar o arquivo para a a pasta `/tmp/` caso consiga, é problema de permissão caso não, tem que ver os grants

Comment: Olá, para /tmp/ eu consigo sim, havia verificado isso. Para outro diretório o Mysql não deixa exportar?

Comment: Veja como esta as permissões da pasta `/var/lib/mysql/` e atributa as mesmas permissões, como esta pasta é gerenciada pelo mysql, é só replicar as permissões